# How to fix (RubyInstaller::Runtime::DllDirectory::WinApiError) in ruby on windows?

Tags: ruby, compiler-errors, rubygems, runtime-error, runtime

while Implementing ruby2d in the code i get this error

It's a strange runtime issue

### **Ruby2d Code**

```
require 'ruby2d'
# Set the window size
set width: 300, height: 200
# Create a new shape
s = Square.new
# Give it some color
s.color = 'red'
# Show the window
 show
```

### Error

```
  8: from R.rb:1:in `<main>'
    7: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:39:in `require'
    6: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `rescue in require'
    5: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `require'
    4: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/ruby2d-0.5.1/lib/ruby2d.rb:28:in `<top (required)>'
    3: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/ruby_installer/runtime/singleton.rb:12:in `add_dll_directory'
    2: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/ruby_installer/runtime/singleton.rb:12:in `new'
    1: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/ruby_installer/runtime/dll_directory.rb:50:in `initialize'


*C:/Ruby25- 
x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/ruby_installer/runtime/dll_directory.rb:83:in 
`add_dll_directory_winapi': AddDllDirectory failed for 
C:/Users/Salim/usr/local/bin 
(RubyInstaller::Runtime::DllDirectory::WinApiError)*
```

**Please Help me to fix**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this issue by creating `usr/local/bin` folders in the `C/users/username` directory
and pasted the dlls required which can ne found on [Link for dll](https://github.com/simple2d/simple2d/releases/download/v0.9.0/simple2d-windows-mingw-0.9.0.zip) 
extract it and copy the dll from bin and paste in the new bin directory that you have created .

**Imp**- `usr/local/bin` was my default dll-load directory i hope its the same for others too but please check the error message properly.

Answer (score 2):

You have to run your project from the MINGW 64-bit command prompt. Not from the regular DOS prompt (Windows Command Prompt).

Make sure you follow the instructions here:
http://www.ruby2d.com/learn/windows/

Note the last paragraph:

> ### Using Ruby 2D on Windows
>
> When working with Ruby 2D, **make sure to use a MinGW 64-bit command prompt**, rather than a standard one (cmd.exe) or the “Start Command Prompt with Ruby” found in the Start menu.

Comment: Was just typing something similar when I saw your answer pop-up, lol. This is one of the many reasons I didn't care for Ruby2D, and preferred Gosu, before I ended up just using OpenGL more directly without the "middle-man" libraries.

Comment: when using mingw 64bit command prompt it shows `ruby command not found` But if i run the git bash which is a mingw 64 bit too , the _winapi_ .... error still persists

Comment: i think the path to load the dll directory  should be changed. in the  `dll_directory.rb` or `singleton.rb` file in `C:\Ruby25-x64\lib\ruby\site_ruby\2.5.0\ruby_installer\runtime`directory. if you know how to add the path please let me know with the code snippet